# How to create a Java JSON Object from a Json string?

Tags: java, json, org.json

I'm trying to create a Json Object in java from a Json String but i'm not using it in the proper way since the json object looks empty

Here is my Json arriving from Ajax and it is composed by an array and a single variable:

```
{"arrayUsers":["53","54"],"idMansione":"1"}
```

Here is my Java function where i'm trying to create the Json Object:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

...

    public ResponseEntity<String> assignTask(String json) {

        //Here i'm trying to create the object

        JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
        mainObj.put("arrayUsers", json);
        System.out.print(mainObj); //looks empty

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of the json argument that you use?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);
```

Comment: Not with org.json

Comment: this will work with : import org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: Which is the dependency for "JSONParser" ?

Comment: @Matteo Bruni , try this : import org.json.simple.JSONObject,                          
  Even you can use gson.toJson(), Google API one

Comment: @Developer .parse does not exist after parser

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(json);
```